# Are there any Amazon AWS Loadbalancer GUI tools?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I wonder if there are any Amazon AWS Instance Loadbalancer GUI tools?
Other than ylastic.

Comment: Isn't https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?region=us-east-1#s=LoadBalancers enough? Which kind of properties you need to set to the load balancer servers?

Comment: Sorry, that page returns an error for me, I cannot read the content of it.. I just want attach and remove instances from the loadbalancer.

Comment: At least you should be able to access http://aws.amazon.com/es/console/ then browse to EC2 > NETWORK & SECURITY > Load Balancers (If you have enough credentials). If you can't you should contact Amazon support.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the sole owner of the AWS account you should be able to access elastic load balancer tab, else contact your system admin. If your IE please switch to Mozilla or chrome for better internet experience